Responsive layout to visibility gone
I have a 3 components in xml. linearProgress, tvQuestionNumber, tvQuestion.
TvQuestion's some part is here:
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearProgress" />

When the linearProgress visibility become gone. I want to change like:
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvQuestionNumber" />

How can I make it responsive like that.

After you set the visibility to GONE, add
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) tvQuestion.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.topToBottom = R.id.tvQuestionNumber;
tvQuestion.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


Are there any way to do that in xml ?

@YakupKavak Technically you can but you'll need to use different elements in layout and control it programmatically. The one I provided is much easier and clean

How can we do that by using different elements in layout ?

@YakupKavak Can you explain why you're trying to do it via layout? What's the use case.? Asking because you'll have to manage it programmatically even if you do that. It'll only increase the complexity and there isn't much benefit. It'll be a redundant addition IMO
